# Is it possible to install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, tomcat, tomcat8

It seems that Ubuntu no longer ships Apache Tomcat 8 in the repos as of 20.04, there is only Apache Tomcat 9. I have a school assignment which requries we use Apache Tomcat 8. Is there a way to install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 20.04, or will I have to get a VM with Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can always download and extract the tomcat8 package yourself and use a systemd script like this: https://gist.github.com/zengxs/a697d786b244d7b857d3d006213306a1
(or start the tomcat from within the `bin` folder)

Why is your school assignment bound to a fix version of Tomcat btw?

Cheers
Martin

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a docker image, rather than installing an old package as long as thats allowed by your assignment. Knowing docker comes in very handy for work/containers/K8s and software development/devops.

Install docker desktop (has a gui) - can follow the guide here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/

or

docker-ce (non graphical)
Digital ocean has some good guides https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04

Make sure docker/docker desktop is running.

Then find the image you need on dockerhub.com
go to tomcat https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat then sarch for 8.0

pull the image

```
docker pull tomcat:8.0
```

Then run it

```
docker run -p 80:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

browse to http://localhost/

and you should see the default page for tomcat 8.

Can just use it like that or can build your own customised image with your assignment built in.